# Django Form getting invalid

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, pinax

I am newbie to Django. I have some troubles with forms after moving into new verison. Following,

1, The model

```
class UserProfileDetails(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User)
profilePicture = models.ImageField('Profile Picture',upload_to='static/ProfilePic/', null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

2, The form

```
class imageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=  UserProfileDetails
    fields = ['user','profilePicture']
```

3, And finally the view function

```
def upload_pic(request):
current_user = request.user
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = imageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        pic = form.cleaned_data['profilePicture']
        m = UserProfileDetails(user= current_user.id,profilePicture=pic)
        m.save()
    else:
        raise NotImplemented("What if the user doesn't have an associated profile?")

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:profile'))
```

This code worked with Django 1.8. But after porting to Django 1.10.4, the form is getting invalid. I believe, the problem is with **OneToOneField**.

**IMP**: Also, i am using pinax account app for account management.

Why this form is getting invalid?

Comment: So what an error do you have?

Comment: Its raising the  "raise NotImplemented("What if the user doesn't have an associated profile?"" message, which means the form is getting invalid! ...

Comment: then write correct code, because everyone will wrote you about that

Comment: Well what you mean by correct code?? its just an 'IF' statement!.. else it will redirect to  "polls:profile'".  How  come thats an error, its a hack code (i know)!

Comment: Now according to your code `if request.method == 'POST':` it redirect to `polls:profile`, the last line of your code. As I understand it should be `if form.is_valid():`. Now  i undelete my  answer, and you check out my code and your. Then make changes of your code, if mistake will be still their i will delete my answer, or try to correct it. Ok?

Comment: mark my answer as answer on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form, it doesn't seem as though a correct input has been given for both fields (user and profile picture). My guess is that you aren't sending through the user in the form which means it is invalid. So you are only uploading the image.

You do not need to have 'user' in the form fields attribute as you already access that in the view with 'request.user'. So remove the 'user' field from the form.

Also, to make sure it is correct, change 'user=current_user.id' to 'user=current_user' so you are match instance with instance rather than instance with id.

Comment: That's perfect. You spot it. Thank you.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, i was using this same code in Django 1.8  and it worked (even though there is an error).?? Did you know why ??